# Change Material Design theme dynamicaly with Angular 2 / Meteor

Tags: angular, meteor, themes

I have a Meteor/Angular 2 application and i want to switch a theme when a user click on one of the two available options :

```
<select onChange="changeTheme()">
<option value="blue"> Blue</option>
<option value="gray">Gray</option>
</select>
```

My application load the blue theme by default and it's defined under the main.scss :

```
@import '../node_modules/@angular/material/core/theming/all-theme';
$app-primary: md-palette($md-light-blue, 700, 100, 700);
```

My question is how and where i can change the theme when a user choose a specific one, e-g Gray ? Is that something i should do inside the `Meteor.startup()` function ? or inside a component ?

Thanks

Comment: Here's the answer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40611533/change-theme-dynamicly-with-angular-2-meteor?noredirect=1#comment68457440_40611533