# Change theme dynamicly with Angular 2 / Meteor

Tags: angular, meteor, themes

I have a Meteor/Angular 2 application and i want to change a theme when a user click on one of the two available options :

```
<select onChange="changeTheme()">
<option value="blue"> Blue</option>
<option value="gray">Gray</option>
</select>
```

My application load the blue theme by default and it's defined under the main.scss :

```
@import '../node_modules/@angular/material/core/theming/all-theme';
$app-primary: md-palette($md-light-blue, 700, 100, 700);
```

My question is how and where i can change the theme when a user choose a specific one, e-g Gray ? Is that something i should do inside the Meteor.startup() function ? or inside a component ?

Thanks

Comment: This is more a question for your theme rather than Angular or Meteor. Have a look at the documentation and see what it recommends

Comment: The theme is related to an Angular 2 / Meteor application like mentionned in my question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, you should take a look to the excellent presentation of Kara :
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0q9FOeEELPY

Then, to answer your question, here's how you should do it :

**your-scss-file.scss** :

```
@import '~@angular/material/core/theming/all-theme';

@include md-core();

$primary: md-palette($md-deep-purple);
$accent: md-palette($md-amber);

$theme: md-light-theme($primary, $accent);

@include angular-material-theme($theme);

.dark-theme {
  $dark-p: md-palette($md-deep-purple, 700);
  $dark-a: md-palette($md-amber);

  $dark-t: md-dark-theme($dark-p, $dark-a);

  @include angular-material-theme($dark-t);
}
```

**your-html-file.html** :

```
<div [class.dark-theme]="isDarkTheme">
<button (click)="toggleTheme()">Toggle theme</button>
```

**your-ts-file.ts** :

```
@Component({
  selector: 'your-component-selector',
  templateUrl: './your-html-file.html',
  styleUrls: ['your-scss-file.scss']
})
export class YourComponent implements {
  // by default, if you do not want the dark theme
  private isDarkTheme = false;

  constructor() { }

  toggleTheme() {
    this.isDarkTheme = !this.isDarkTheme;
  }
}
```

Of course, if you need more than a toggle because you have > 2 themes, just pass the class of your theme to the `[class]` propertie instead of doing `[class.dark-theme]="someBoolean"`.

Comment: That's exactly what i was looking for. Now i will just add a variable session to store the theme into a session. Thank you :) I wanted to vote but i can't since i have a score less than 15 :(

Comment: Glad it helped ! :)

Comment: I just get +7 so now i have a score of 16.  I voted :)

Comment: Thank you @Kivo :)

Comment: Do you know how to do exactly the same but with the Kendo UI Angular 2 Controls? Thx

Comment: Problem with this approach is with each new theme you need to edit `your-scss-file.scss` ' for every `component` you have in your project. Imagine the overhead if you are running a large project with multiple developers.  In the pre-web-components era we could just replace 1 css file with another

Comment: Umh no, why do you say that @jackOfAll ? Read the last line of the post

Comment: @Maxime: What about the need to generate `.theme-1{ span{color :$spanClr}}  .theme-2{ span{color :$spanClr}}   .theme-3{ span{color :$spanClr}}` , with 3 different values for `$spanClr` ? Thus repeated the same styling 3 times and then adding them to the component statically at compile. And sadly these styles unlike global styles can't be lazy loaded either. If we could lazy load the styles for each component that would be good.

Comment: Thank you for linking the video!! It's amazing