# UI Skinning : Is it possible to support multiple skins in Angular 4 with View Encapsulation & Shadow DOM?

Tags: css, angular, themes, skin, skinning

Since Angular uses view encapsulation is it possible to support multiple themes in Angular 2? I mean the user should be able to click on a button and change the color theming of the whole application.

PS: I am using Angular 4 with angular-cli with SASS support.

Currently I am able to generate static themes with a `_variable.scss` file which is imported in each component's sass based stylesheet.

But, my requirement is end user should be able to choose his own color theme.

Ideally in non-angular websites I would just add a new compiled `css` file to the `<head>` tag using javascript. Since shadow DOM generates separate `style` for each component and adds them in to the `<head>` how I change the style for each component dynamically?

Comment: Well usually you just switch the class. Can't see how this would be specific to Angular aside from using [`ngClass`](https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass) to implement the effective change in the template.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change theme dynamicly with Angular 2 / Meteor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40611533/change-theme-dynamicly-with-angular-2-meteor)

Comment: @NeilLunn : But then wouldn't that mean I have to make changes for each new component to support 2 classes. It'll not be one time one place change

Comment: Depends really. Angular material docs show much the same thing. Mind you all those components have `ViewEncapsulation.None`.

Comment: Yeah.. I don't how much ViewEncapsulation.None will effect performance. If would have preferred to have a central place where I can configure the color variables  and not bother for each component :(

Comment: @NeilLunn: this also means double the amount of css generated for each skin.

Answer (score 0):

you can try the css method **var()**, for more details can read this [blog](https://medium.com/@nijaunjal/multiple-css-themes-in-angular-277dfaadda03)